# What are new labels (imap/trash and imap/sent) in my gmail account?

Tags: gmail, label

I am really confused about these labels (imap/trash and imap/sent) in my Gmail account.
I don't know why they are there?

One of them in connecting to my inbox, mean when I read a new email from inbox I lose a number from imap/sent unread count.

Comment: hey man, why downvote? i am new here...

Comment: Your question isn't really on topic on this site. It might be migrated to another StackExchange site where this question is more appropriate.

Comment: @Oliver Salzburg thanks for the comment. yes sir...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably being created by what ever imap client you use to check your gmail account.  The client assuming that the folder for trash and sent is located in a specific place but google keep it elsewhere.

When you view gmail via the browser these folders created by your imap client show up as labels.